# Unable to decrypt aes-192-gcm

Tags: aes-gcm, encryption

I'm using nodejs to encrypt and decrypt aes-192-gcm

here's my code:

```
const encrypted = decrypt.encryptText('aes-192-gcm', 'FnpkKuIoqZL5B3tnE0Htmg==', '1z3FtB6OitmFOIsP', 'helloWorld', 'base64');
const de = decrypt.decryptText('aes-192-gcm', 'FnpkKuIoqZL5B3tnE0Htmg==', '1z3FtB6OitmFOIsP', encrypted, 'utf-8');
console.log(encrypted);
console.log(de);
```

Functions used:

```
 function encryptText(cipher_alg, key, iv, text, encoding) {

        var cipher = crypto.createCipheriv(cipher_alg, key, iv);

        encoding = encoding || "binary";

        var result = cipher.update(text, "utf8", encoding);
        result += cipher.final(encoding);

        return result;
    }

    function decryptText(cipher_alg, key, iv, text, encoding) {

        const decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv(cipher_alg, key, iv);

        encoding = encoding || "binary";

        let result = decipher.update(text, encoding);
        result += decipher.final();

        return result;
    }
```

The error I'm getting:

```
Unsupported state or unable to authenticate data
```

Answer (score 2):

Couple of problems

1. you are passing a wrong encoding format for the decryptText()
2. AuthTag is required when using GCM, CCM and OCB.

I have attached a sample code based on the snippet you have shared.

```
var cipherTag;

const encrypted = encryptText('aes-192-gcm', 'FnpkKuIoqZL5B3tnE0Htmg==', '1z3FtB6OitmFOIsP', 'helloWorld', 'base64');
const de = decryptText('aes-192-gcm', 'FnpkKuIoqZL5B3tnE0Htmg==', '1z3FtB6OitmFOIsP', encrypted, 'base64');
console.log(encrypted);
console.log(de);

function encryptText(cipher_alg, key, iv, text, encoding) {

    var cipher = crypto.createCipheriv(cipher_alg, key, iv);

    encoding = encoding || "binary";

    var result = cipher.update(text, "utf8", encoding);
    result += cipher.final(encoding);
    cipherTag = cipher.getAuthTag();
    return result;
}

function decryptText(cipher_alg, key, iv, text, encoding) {

    const decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv(cipher_alg, key, iv);

    encoding = encoding || "binary";
    decipher.setAuthTag(cipherTag);
    let result = decipher.update(text, encoding, 'utf8');
    result+= decipher.final('utf8');
    return result.toString();
}
```

// Will output

```
b2SMQRBt/EgNgQ==
helloWorld
```

Comment: I don't think setAAD is required here, the problem is she is missing the authTag

Answer (score 2):

The crypto module of NodeJS uses OpenSSL. This API has special parameters for GCM / AEAD ciphers. Methods to use them have been added to the API, such as [`getAuthTag`](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_cipher_getauthtag) and [`setAuthTag`](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_decipher_setauthtag_buffer). Without the latter, the method *always* throws an exception for GCM mode decryption. The tag is (fortunately) *not* considered part of the ciphertext in NodeJS / OpenSSL. Other languages runtimes - such as Java - do consider it part of the ciphertext.